# how to set session attribute from a hidden field?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

is it possible to set a session attribute using JSTL from a hidden input in the jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`<c:set>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) to set an attribute in an arbitrary scope and you can use `${param}` to access a request parameter.

```
<c:set var="foo" value="${param.foo}" scope="session" />
```

This will basically do `session.setAttribute("foo", request.getParameter("foo"));` during rendering of the response of the JSP result page with this line where the form is been submitted to. In this example, the hidden field should have the name `foo`.

If you actually need to set it *before* forwarding the request/response to the JSP, then you'll need to do this (indirectly) in the responsible controlling/postprocessing servlet class where the form is been submitted to.

If you actually need to set it *during* displaying the form, then just set the value directly using `<c:set>` instead of passing from a hidden input. E.g.

```
<c:set var="foo" value="theValue" scope="session" />
```